# Get a list of all running pods for own service

Tags: spring, kubernetes

### The situation

- I have a Spring Boot service running inside Kubernetes
- Multiple instance are running (the kubernetes deployment has multiple replicas configured)
- I have an incoming HTTP from outside the cluster that hits on of the instances
- I want to relay the fact to all other instances

### Question

Is there an easy, no external things needed, solution to find a list of "all pods of my service" ? I think I remember that this could be possible via DNS resolution but my Google-Fu seems to weak to find something.

Of course I can always to this via some other solution (e.g. Redis, Kafka, whatever) but since I only need this for a one-off feature I would like to not introduce any moving parts and keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internal K8s DNS would only get you the IP-address of the service. Luckily, there is the Endpoints resource exactly for the purpose of getting the Pods that back a Service.

With kubectl you can check endpoints out like this:

```
kubectl get endpoints nginx -o yaml
```

With this command you get hold of the Pod names:

```
kubectl get endpoints nginx -o=jsonpath='{.subsets[*].addresses[*].targetRef.name}'
```

To execute the same thing from your Spring Boot app, you can try to make use of the official [Kubernetes Java client library.](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/)

Answer (score 2):

You can list all pods behind a service by running

```
$ kubectl get endpoints <service-name> -o=jsonpath='{.subsets[*].addresses[*].ip}' | tr ' ' '\n' | xargs -I % kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.podIP=%
```